# Function returns empty vector when built in Release

Tags: c++, vector, release

Here is the function:

```
std::vector<int> CTat964Drs::ExecuteMultiplePtgsWithStatus(int numberOfPatTimeGroups,
                                                           int *ptgHandle,
                                                           double Timeout,
                                                           int numTimeExecute,
                                                           T964DRS_BURST_COMPLETE Mode,
                                                           int numErrorsArr[],
                                                           bool burstTimeoutArr[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int numErrors = 0;
    bool burstTimeout = false;
    std::vector<int> multipleStatus;

    multipleStatus.resize(numberOfPatTimeGroups);

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfPatTimeGroups; i++)
    {
        if (!m_ptgArray || ptgHandle < 0 || !m_ptgArray[ptgHandle[i]])
        {
            multipleStatus[i] = DRS_ERRCD_INVALID_HANDLE;
            continue;
        }

        if (burstTimeoutArr != NULL)
        {
            // For this case, timeout is reported in burstTimeout. It is not reported in status.
            multipleStatus[i] = ((CTat964DrsPatTimeGrpPtr)(m_ptgArray[ptgHandle[i]]))->
                    ExecutePtg(Timeout, numTimeExecute, Mode, &numErrors, &burstTimeout);

            burstTimeoutArr[i] = burstTimeout;
        }
        else
        {
            // For this case, timeout is reported in status.
            multipleStatus[i] = ((CTat964DrsPatTimeGrpPtr)(m_ptgArray[ptgHandle[i]]))->
                    ExecutePtg(Timeout, numTimeExecute, Mode, &numErrors);
        }

        numErrorsArr[i] = numErrors;
    }

    return multipleStatus;
}
```

And here is the usage in the calling program, which is also a DLL.

```
std::vector<int> multipleStatus;

multipleStatus = m_T940->ExecuteMultiplePtgsWithStatus(m_PTGCount, 
                                                       _ptgHandles,
                                                       _maxTime,
                                                       _loopCnt,
                                                       T964DRS_SYNCHRONOUS,
                                                       numErrorsArr,
                                                       burstTimeoutArr)
```

The code works fine when the DLL that contains ExecuteMultiplePtgsWithStatus() is built in Debug configuration, but the function returns an empty vector when it is built in Release configuration.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Same *exact* tool chains and runtime libraries built both DLLs? You're kind of playing with fire throwing standard containers across module boundaries, reason why I asked. And *both* DLLs are built Debug and/or Release, right?

Comment: The simple answer is `numberOfPatTimeGroups` is zero when called in release mode.  Not enough code for anything other than a guess.  You didn't even include the code where you check if the vector is empty.

Comment: As Retired Ninja said... I also saw something similar. The only way the result could have zero elements is if `numberOfPatTimeGroups` was zero for some reason (assuming that everything was build with the same toolset [as WhozCraig pointeded out]). Dig back further in your code. Also, debugging is incredibly useful.

Comment: Both DLLs were built with Visual Studio 2010.  The value of numberOfPatTimeGroups is not 0. I verified this in the debugger. I also built the calling DLL in Release mode so both DLLs were built in Release, and the function returns an empty vector.  I verified this by including debug code in the calling program that checks multipleStatus.empty() and displays a message if it is true.  If this is not the correct way to return a vector from a DLL, what is the correct way?  Thanks.

Comment: I also displayed multipleStatus.size() in the calling DLL.  It is 2 when the DLL that contains ExecuteMultiplePtgsWithStatus() is built in Debug and 0 when it is built in Release. I will add the same debug code to ExecuteMultiplePtgsWithStatus() to verify that the size is 2 before it returns. The DLL that contains ExecuteMultiplePtgsWithStatus() uses __cdecl calling convention.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: I included debug code in ExecuteMultiplePtgsWithStatus() that logs numberOfPatTimeGroups and multipleStatus.size() right before the return statement.  It prints "ExecuteMultiplePtgsWithStatus received 2 PTGs and is returning vector size 2". But the calling program receives an empty vector regardless of whether it is built in Debug or Release. The same test case works fine if the DLL that contains ExecuteMultiplePtgsWithStatus() is built in Debug.  It only returns an empty vector if it is built in Release. Is there a better way to return a vector from a DLL? Thanks.